# React Native navigate using Touchable Opacity

Tags: react-native

I want to make the Play button to navigate to the play screen. I created a an app class as the main file. Then in my cluster1, I am able to press a play button. But I don't know how to navigate the play button to the play class screen.

This is my App Class

```
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <AppNavigator/>
  </View>
);}}
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Cluster1: { 
  screen: Cluster1,
  },
  Play: { 
  screen: Play,
  },
 });
```

This is my Cluster1 Class

```
export default class Cluster1 extends Component{
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Choose the Mood Cluster to listen',};
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <SectionList          
             renderItem={({item,index})=>{
                 return(
                <SectionListItem  item={item} index={index}> </SectionListItem>);}} 
                    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
                        return (<SectionHeader section={section} />);}}
                          sections={ClusterData}
                          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}>
            </SectionList>
        </View>      
    );
}}
class SectionHeader extends Component {
    render() {
        const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
            Cluster1: { screen: Cluster1},
             Play: { screen: Play},
           });
        return (
            <View style={styles.header}>  
                <Text style={styles.headertext}>
                {this.props.section.title}       
                </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Play')}}> Play</TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }}
```

This is my Play class

```
export default class Play extends Component{
static navigationOptions = {
    headerMode: 'none', };
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Play Screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }{
```

What do i add in for my touchableopacity statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this. Use navigation option to navigate the component

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
 Cluster1: { screen: Cluster1},
  Play: { screen: Play},
});

 <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Play')}}> Play</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I added in the statement but they said "Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function! ( Trying to add a 'RCTRawText [text: >' to a 'RCTView')"

Comment: try the code like    <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Play')}}> Play</TouchableOpacity>

Comment: `const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Cluster1: { 
      screen: Cluster1,
      },
  Play: { 
      screen: Play,
      },
  });`
This is how I define my stacknavigator

Comment: sorry where do i put my const Appnavigator? I still get error. :(
Thanks for your help